# Python & Plotly: custom colors to pie chart via dictionary

Tags: python, colors, plotly

I'm creating reporting engine and i'm struggling to get customization work as i want to. I have data which contains criticalities from 1-10 and i'd like to have it so that in pie, the rating 10 allways gets red color, rating 9 orange and so on..

My current code is following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.figure_factory as FF

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

crit = [1, 10, 2, 6, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 6, 9, 10, 5, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4, 9, 2, 8, 7, 1, 1, 7, 3, 9, 9, 6, 6, 8, 9, 6, 7, 5, 9, 8, 4, 4, 5, 6, 2, 9, 9, 4, 6, 9, 9]

fig = {
  "data": [
    {
      "values": crit,
      "labels": crit,
      "domain": {"x": [0, .48]},
      "name": "Criticality",
      "marker": {'colors': [
                     '#e6f2ff',
                     '#99ccff',
                     '#ccccff',
                     '#cc99ff',
                     '#ff99ff',
                     '#ff6699',
                     '#ff9966',
                     '#ff6600',
                     '#ff5050',
                     '#ff0000'
                    ]
                },
      "textinfo":"percent+label",
      "textfont": {'color': '#FFFFFF', 'size': 15},
      "hole": .4,
      "type": "pie"
    } ],
    "layout": {
        "title":"Criticalities",
        "annotations": [
            {
                "font": {
                    "size": 25,
                    "color": '#5A5A5A'
                },
                "showarrow": False,
                "text": "2018",
                "x": 0.20,
                "y": 0.5
            }
        ]
    }
}



py.iplot(fig, filename='pie-custom-colors')
```

but this results as with following diagram:

[image: graph]

Is there a way to map these colors based on a dictonary like:

```
colors = { 
'10':'#ff0000'
'9':'#ff5050'
etc.. }
```

Bonus question: Is there way to sort the icons on right side as well from 10->1

Comment: Please replace `df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', delimiter=';', error_bad_lines=False)` by some sample data (just copy paste it here) to allow people to run your example on their side. This will increase the chances of you getting a correct answer quickly. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, i didn't think it was relevant for the question but done :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Dictionary of colors**

Let's suppose you have your `color_dict`. Plotly takes an array of colors with has the same length as the vectors of labels and values. So, you have to construct this array yourself, for example like this:

```
import numpy as np
crit = np.array([1, 10, 2, 6, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 6, 9, 10, 5, 8, 3, 8,
        5, 4, 9, 2, 8, 7, 1, 1, 7, 3, 9, 9, 6, 6, 8, 9, 6, 7, 5,
        9, 8, 4, 4, 5, 6, 2, 9, 9, 4, 6, 9, 9])
color_dict = {'1':'#e6f2ff', '2':'#99ccff', '3':'#ccccff',
              '4':'#cc99ff', '5':'#ff99ff', '6':'#ff6699', 
              '7':'#ff9966', '8':'#ff6600', '9':'#ff5050', 
              '10':'#ff0000'}
colors = np.array([''] * len(crit), dtype = object)
for i in np.unique(crit):
    colors[np.where(crit == i)] = color_dict[str(i)]
```

Now to plot simply use `"marker" : {'colors': colors}` for the colors.

This will give you the plot with the right colors.

**Bonus question**

Pie charts are sorted by values by default, however, you can sort using the labels instead using `"sort":False`.

Unfortunately, this won't work with the way you construct the chart as it will take the order in which the data comes: i.e. 1, 10, 2, 6, etc. which is not what you want.

It is better to give Plotly the already aggregated figures per value like this:

```
labels = np.unique(crit) #or simply = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
values = np.bincount(crit)[1:]       #[5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 8, 3, 5, 10, 2]
```

Now, no need to put the colors in some dictionary as they already have the same shape as your data.

```
fig = {
  "data": [
    {
      "values": values,
      "labels": labels,
      "domain": {"x": [0, .48]},
      "name": "Criticality",
      "sort": False,
      "marker": {'colors': ['#e6f2ff', '#99ccff', '#ccccff',
                            '#cc99ff', '#ff99ff', '#ff6699',
                            '#ff9966', '#ff6600', '#ff5050', 
                            '#ff0000']},
      "textinfo":"percent+label",
      "textfont": {'color': '#FFFFFF', 'size': 15},

      "hole": .4,
      "type": "pie"
    } ],
    "layout": {
        "title":"Criticalities",
        "annotations": [
            {
                "font": {
                    "size": 25,
                    "color": '#5A5A5A'
                },
                "showarrow": False,
                "text": "2018",
                "x": 0.20,
                "y": 0.5
            }
        ]
    }
}

py.iplot(fig)
```

This gives the following result, which, I believe, is what you want:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant - exactly what i was looking for + more - thank you!

Comment: Glad this helped. If the answer really helped, then please accept it and/or upvote to make it easier for others in the same situation to find it quickly.